# how to play video when the video is in viewport and pause it when i scroll it in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

This is my video player widget, I want the video to pause when to scroll away from the video and I want it to play automatically when I scroll to the video , its a social media app

> ```
> class Videoplayer extends StatefulWidget {
>       const Videoplayer({Key? key, this.width = 400, this.height = 400})
>           : super(key: key);
>     
>       final double? width;
>       final double? height;
>     
>       @override
>       _VideoplayerState createState() => _VideoplayerState();
>     }
>     
>     class _VideoplayerState extends State<Videoplayer> {
>       late VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController,
>           _videoPlayerController2,
>           _videoPlayerController3;
>     
>       late CustomVideoPlayerController _customVideoPlayerController;
>       late CustomVideoPlayerWebController _customVideoPlayerWebController;
>     
>       final CustomVideoPlayerSettings _customVideoPlayerSettings =
>           const CustomVideoPlayerSettings();
>     
>       final CustomVideoPlayerWebSettings _customVideoPlayerWebSettings =
>           CustomVideoPlayerWebSettings(
>         src: longVideo,
>       );
>       void initState() {
>         super.initState();
>     
>         _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.network(
>           longVideo,
>         )..initialize().then((value) => setState(() {}));
>         _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(video240);
>         _videoPlayerController3 = VideoPlayerController.network(video480);
>         _customVideoPlayerController = CustomVideoPlayerController(
>           context: context,
>           videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController,
>           customVideoPlayerSettings: _customVideoPlayerSettings,
>           additionalVideoSources: {
>             "240p": _videoPlayerController2,
>             "480p": _videoPlayerController3,
>             "720p": _videoPlayerController,
>           },
>         );
>     
>         _customVideoPlayerWebController = CustomVideoPlayerWebController(
>           webVideoPlayerSettings: _customVideoPlayerWebSettings,
>         );
>       }
>     
>       @override
>       void dispose() {
>         _customVideoPlayerController.dispose();
>         super.dispose();
>       }
>     
>       @override
>       Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>         return SafeArea(
>           child: ListView(
>             children: [
>               kIsWeb
>                   ? Expanded(
>                       child: CustomVideoPlayerWeb(
>                         customVideoPlayerWebController:
>                             _customVideoPlayerWebController,
>                       ),
>                     )
>                   : CustomVideoPlayer(
>                       customVideoPlayerController: _customVideoPlayerController,
>                     ),
>               CupertinoButton(
>                 child: const Text("Play Fullscreen"),
>                 onPressed: () {
>                   if (kIsWeb) {
>                     _customVideoPlayerWebController.setFullscreen(true);
>                     _customVideoPlayerWebController.play();
>                   } else {
>                     _customVideoPlayerController.setFullscreen(true);
>                     _customVideoPlayerController.videoPlayerController.play();
>                   }
>                 },
>               ),
>             ],
>           ),
>         );
>       }
>     }
> ```

this is a social media app , this widget is inside userpost , so that if a user scrolls i want the video to play automatically if the userpost contain a video and i want the video to pause once the user scroll down

Answer (score 1):

You could use a **NotificationListener** widget to achieve this.

Create a value to hold the current position of your player

```
double _pixels = 100;
```

Then use that value to compare whenever the user scrolls

```
NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
onNotification: (ScrollNotification scrollInfo) {
  if (scrollInfo.metrics.pixels > _pixels) {
   // User scrolled down
   _customVideoPlayerWebController.pause();
  } else {
   // User scrolled up
   _customVideoPlayerWebController.play();
  }
  _pixels = scrollInfo.metrics.pixels;
  return false;
},
child: CustomVideoPlayerWeb(),
)
```

Comment: this doesnot solve the problem as it pauses and plays all the videos in each and every post

Comment: I don't fully understand the context of this, but you definitely could tweak this logic to play/pause a specific video.